# Matlab set range of inputs and step

Tags: matlab

I have this signal:

```
x(t) = t*sin(m*pi*t)*heaviside(-m*pi-t)+t*cos(k*pi*t)*heaviside(t-k*pi)+sin(k*pi*t)*cos(m*pi*t)*(heaviside(t+m*pi)-heaviside(t-k*pi));
```

and I want to calculate the values only from  -5pi to 5pi  with a step of pi/100 using Matlab. How could I do it?

Comment: You haven't defined `m` or `k`. But assuming they are constants: `my_t = -5*pi:pi/100:5*pi; x(my_t)` will do. This is about as basic as it gets in MATLAB, thus I suggest going through [the MathWork's own tutorials](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/index.html) to get acquainted with the basic syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have defined `m` and `k` somewhere, and you have the [matlab symbolic toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic.html) which provides the [heaviside function](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/heaviside.html), this is how it is done:

```matlab
% First we define the function
x = @(t) t*sin(m*pi*t)*heaviside(-m*pi-t)+t*cos(k*pi*t)*heaviside(t-k*pi)+sin(k*pi*t)*cos(m*pi*t)*(heaviside(t+m*pi)-heaviside(t-k*pi));

% Then we define the values for which we want to compute the function
t_values = -5*pi:pi/100:5*pi;

% Finally we evaluate the function
x_values = x(t_values)
```

**Details**

1. First line we define your function as an [anonymous function](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) which is a handy tool in matlab.
2. Then we create a vector of values from -5pi to 5*pi with steps of pi/100. For this we use the [matlab colon syntax](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html). It makes it short and efficient.
3. Finally we evaluate the function on each of the `t_values` by passing the vector to the anonymous function.

Note: If you don't have the symbolic toolbox, you could easily implement `heaviside` yourself.

Comment: [`heavyside()`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/heaviside.html) belongs to the Symbolic Math toolbox.